# Can 追撃 be used as following attacks?

Tags: nuances

[image]

Here 追撃 seems to be used as follow up attacks, or combo. According to the kanjis, it would definitely make sense, but every dictionary I'm looking at is translating it to "chase" or "pursuit".

**Edit**: This other definition is very clear in Japanese dictionaries, but Japanese-English dictionaries all translate it to "pursuit" without mentioning the second definition or the nuance. The first definition seems to also imply some kind of hit, so I think even "pursuit" is not enough to convey the full meaning. It's literally "follow-up attack to a weak or fleeing enemy" in one word. "Pursuit" in English is simply 追う.

> 敗走する敵を追いかけ**てうつこと**。**劣勢にある相手をさらに攻めること**。**おいうち**。

Comment: The difference from *combo* is that 追撃 tends to be used when the opponent is down of off-guard. Traditionally in military contexts, 追撃 means "chase (of *withdrawing* fighters)".

Comment: As you mention, it is mean pursuit. (mostly on military and martial arts). Fact: it is same letter same meaning as traditional chinese. (敵=enemy ). Roughly mean in english also mean pursuit enemy isnt?

Comment: @EdwardChanJW In some contexts yes, but not this one. Pursuit will be a good translation if you're following someone in order to catch or do something to them. In this specific context, 追撃 is used for the various attacks you perform while the opponent is launched in the air, so it can't be translated as "pursuit". There's just no equivalent word in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. You may want to look at [追い打ち(撃ち/討ち)](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%BF%BD%E3%81%84%E6%92%83%E3%81%A1).

> 2: 弱っているところに*重ねて打撃を与え*、さらに厳しい状態に追いやること。
> *To strike an additional blow to a weakened state, making it even harder.*